# Why did JESUS keep his messanic misson a secret?

Tags: messiah, messianic-secret

If Jesus in Mark chapter 1 casts out demons and heals lepers ,why did he want to keep his messiahship a secret?

Comment: Welcome, Mercy! This question will probably be closed because there is no scriptural reference and it's primarily opinion based. For theological questions or questions focused on doctrine, please ask at Christianity Stackexchange, since this forum is focused on interpreting specific passages in the Bible.

Comment: this is also related https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/why-did-jesus-praise-god-for-hiding-teachings-from-wise-and-learned-people/77405#77405 and I think my answer fits to your question https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/77405/44739

Answer (score 0):

To fulfill the prophecies?

(Mattew 12:16-21)

> And charged them that they should not make him known: That it might be fulfilled which was spoken by Esaias the prophet, saying, Behold my servant, whom I have chosen; my beloved, in whom my soul is well pleased: I will put my spirit upon him, and he shall shew judgment to the Gentiles. He shall not strive, nor cry; neither shall any man hear his voice in the streets. A bruised reed shall he not break, and smoking flax shall he not quench, till he send forth judgment unto victory. And in his name shall the Gentiles trust.

Because the very acts are fulfilling prophecy regarding the Messiah and speak for themselves?

(John 5:36)

> But I have greater witness than that of John: for the works which the Father hath given me to finish, the same works that I do, bear witness of me, that the Father hath sent me.

(Luke 24:44)

> And he said unto them, These are the words which I spake unto you, while I was yet with you, that all things must be fulfilled, which were written in the law of Moses, and in the prophets, and in the psalms, concerning me.